# How to make Darktable work in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

When I open a RAW NEF (Nikon) image in GIMP, the dialog says:

```
GIMP Message

Opening '/path/to/file/_DSC0001.NEF' failed: There is no RAW loader installed to open 'Raw Nikon' files.

GIMP currently supports these RAW loaders:
- darktable (http://www.darktable.org/), at least 1.7
- RawTherapee (http://rawtherapee.com/), at least 5.2

Please install one of them in order to load RAW files.
```

I installed DarkTable with:

```
brew cask install darktable
```

and have version 2.6.3.1 installed. Now the user interface does not show that error message, so GIMP detected DarkTable.

If I open an NEF image in GIMP through the command-line,  but it shows `Opening /path/to/file/_DSC0001.NEF` in the bottom bar and is still responsive. If I open it through the Open file dialog, the dialog remains open and the rest of the dialog is greyed out.

How can I make darktable work with GIMP?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, DarkTable works with GIMP, but is launched as a separate program in the background, which is why it seems that nothing happens. Close that program and GIMP then displays the image.

Comment: You might want to let the darktable developers know that this happens on your platform - macOS, if I interpret that package manager correctly?

Comment: Done: https://github.com/darktable-org/darktable/issues/3691

Comment: And I was advised to file as a GIMP issue: https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gimp/issues/4345